# Composite PK without key property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, composite-primary-key

I using manual mapping entity in my Code First on EF5 project and would like to use FKs as composite PK. I have only navigation properties in mapping class (not FK) as mentioned below:

```
class MyMapping
{
  public virtual Mapped1 {get;set;}
  public virtual Mapped2 {get;set;}
}
```

I do not want to add fields like 'int Mapped1FK'/'int Mapped2FK', but I cannot find how to specify composite key in this case.

I assume that it should be something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyMapping>()
  .HasKey(k => k.Mapped1)
  .HasKey(k => k.Mapped2);
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyMapping>()
  .HasKey(k => { k.Mapped1, k.Mapped2} );
```

but I do not know what exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use navigation properties as primary key properties (no matter if composite or not). Key properties must have a primitive type - like `int` or `string` or `Guid`, etc.

Comment: I supposed that EF creates primitive property transparently for cases when I specify, for example, one-to-one relation, only with navigation properties? That is the case I asked about.

Comment: @AlexG.P.: Yes, that's true for **Foreign Key properties**, but not for **(Primary) Key properties**. If one of your foreign keys is a (or part of a) primary key at the same time you are forced to expose this FK as primitive property in your model. You cannot work with the navigation property alone anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As Slauma described it is impossible to do what I want without introducing primitive FK properties.

So I decided to work with my mapping entities as with ordinary POCO - inherits base class with

```
public int Id {get;set;}
```

declaration and use it as PK.

Also, in other sources, was recommended following, due architecture senses: when you converting simple mapping (2 FKs) to complex mapping (2FKs + custom field(s)) it becomes an ordinary entity as any other in project and should has the same constraints and structure.